# How to communicate with external webapp in Sabre Red App

Tags: sabre

I'm developing a Sabre Red App, with the intention of using a WebkitView to present our web-application. I'm aware that there are several ways how a WebkitView subclass can communicate with HTML/JS hosted locally as plugin-resource. However, what's the best approach to exchange data (pref. JSON) between a Red App and an external web-application?

Options I've looked into:

1. Create a local index.html as plugin-resource, load the web-application in an iframe, and then go WebkitView <-> index.html <-> iFrame/web-application. Seems a bit of a hack, and I'm not sure the Red Workspace will always allow that index.html <-> iframe communication (isn't that cross-site?)
2. Use the WebkitView#executeJavaScript(), but I can't see how the web-application could send a JSON object back

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Red App example using an extension point 'com.sabre.edge.platform.optional.webkit.js.handler' works, but *only* when using a WebkitView subclass. Subclassing BrowserView, the JS object was *not* present.

For the other way round, we decided to use com.sabre.edge.cf.webapp.services.WebViewForwardingService to call a JS function. (be sure to include 'com.sabre.edge.cf.webapp.services' as plugin dependency)

Answer (score 0):

From the Red App you can render the remote URL, like if it was a browser. The actual Web App does not all need to be bundled with the Plugin.

Or is the intention to bundle all the HTML/JS files with the plugin on the client.

Comment: thanks. Using a WebkitView to render the remote URL works, but what if I want provide a button in the remote web app which eventually sends a JSON object/string to my Red App? How does that communication channel work?

Comment: Normally you would build a Java Class Proxy, that allows communication between your Web page and Java Client code, through a Java Script interface on your browser plugin extension that is rendering your page. Easily accomplished.